# How to debug QDomElement in QtXml?

Tags: c++, debugging, qt, qtxml

I've got a **QDomElement, and I would like to debug it**, i.e. see it as plain text in debug console. In order to output it with qDebug(), it needs to be in QString format, however I don't see any conversion method from a QDomElement nor a QDomNode.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in operator for streaming DOM elements to QDebug.  You could write one easily enough, something like:

```
QDebug operator<<(QDebug dbg, const QDomNode& node)
{
  QString s;
  QTextStream str(&s, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  node.save(str, 2);
  dbg << qPrintable(s);
  return dbg;
}
```

Comment: Just edited your answer so that QDebug is used as a reference, in order to be declared using only a forward-declaration on QDebug. Your answer addresses perfectly my question, so I'll choose your answer instead of mine. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Use QTextStream:

```
QTextStream lTS(stdout);
lTS << lMyDomElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you `#include <QDebug>` QDebug would act as TextStream itself.
i.e. `qDebug()<< lMyDomElement;` would be enough)

Comment: Actually, not with my config (gcc4.2, Qt 4.6.3). Hence my question. Maybe the implicit cast is not discovered? Maybe add the right (ugly) cast?

Comment: well... then your initial version is better.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also come across similar situations, in that case my best bet is to make use of the `QDomDocument` which this `QDomElement` is part of. So I would say you cannot get a direct way to access the `QDomElement` but you can achieve that using the QDomDocument.

For this you need to ensure that your `QDomDocument` gets updated with the recent `QDomElement` and then use `QDomDocument::toString()` which would return you the whole document as a QString.

Here is the [Qt reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdomdocument.html#toString).

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a strategy, but something more simple should be prefered, IMHO. Thanks anyway.